# Does Qt have a mechanism like the `file` utility, to read info about an executable?

Tags: c++, qt5

I need to print information about some executables. Usually on Linux this can be done by running `file executable` and various info will be returned.

Example:

```
$ file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
    interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

$ file ri-t.o
ri-t.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, UCB RISC-V, RVC, double-float ABI, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Now, I know I could use `QProcess` to run `file ... and parse the output, but I need a portable (i.e. Windows) way or this doesn't happen at all. To be perfectly clear here, I want to read basic info like which CPU the executable targets and possibly other stuff (i.e. if it's stripped etc.). Also, I don't mind messing with regex to "extract" my string (i.e. x86-64).

Can I do this with Qt5 easily or should I conditionally compile my own code? Even then, where should I begin?

Comment: What do you mean "Portable" i.e. Windows? either you need a portable library or Windows API.

Comment: I would avoid introducing another dependency. If Qt can't do it, I will have to learn how `file` does it and do it by my self. Thank you for your advise and your time.

Comment: I don't think Qt has the `file` functionality builtin.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyway, since I want this functionality for KDbg, I can use gdb's `info target` command, since (among others) it produces this output: `file type elf64-x86-64` Thank you.